# magento 1.9 customize theme

Tags: magento-1.9, css, customize

Can somebody tell me where is the path of the file that connects backend custom styling ( customize theme design ) with frontend? 
or how to connect backend theme design customize option with frontend?

Comment: can you please share more about what you want to achieve?

Comment: In backend by default there are no options to customize at designing  ( CSS level) level

Comment: where is the path where the  css file which are located in  public-html / media / css linked with.. i mean are thier links are written in any .xml or .phtml or in database?

Comment: check below answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking abut css and js files which are included in default theme. Then below suggestion may work as solution.

`/var/www/html/yourwebsite.com/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml`

Under `<block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">`

In this file you will found default css and js in xml format like below

```
  .................................
  <block type="page/js_cookie" name="js_cookies" template="page/js/cookie.phtml"/>

                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/styles.css</stylesheet></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles-ie.css</name><params/><if>lt IE 8</if></action>
                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/widgets.css</stylesheet></action>
                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/print.css</stylesheet><params>media="print"</params></action>
.........................
```

You can add you CSS or/and js in the same format as well, ( recommended but in your custom theme).

To check these files, just open `view-source` your website ( ctrl + u ) to confirm these files.

Note : There is two ways to add CSS to head section first using `addCss` and anotherone `addItem`.

```
<action method="addCss">
    <stylesheet>css/javcustom.css</stylesheet>
</action>
```

**or**

```
<action method="addItem">
    <type>skin_css</type>
    <name>css/javcustom.css</name>
</action>
```

Hope it helps you a bit.
Thank You.

Comment: rajan thaks for your answer but the problem here is that omce i added a custom css in custom css option like this -> .#slideshow{margin: 80px; positin:relative'} etc... and after doing this my theme stoped to display backend's color and fonts changes on frontend. then i deleted that code but the error is still there. what could be the error?

Comment: custom css option  ?? backend admin pannel or in some css files.

Comment: backend admin panel

Comment: chare screenshot, if possible